# -XX:+UseParNewGC parameter for single CPU environment

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We are using CMS gc for our java application. We wonder what would happen if we set gc parameter as -XX:+UseParNewGC instead of let it be the default in a single CPU environment. Will it change performance? If we use -server flag, parallel copying collector will be taken by jvm or we should always explicitly mention it?

Comment: sorry for grammer mistake.i actually tried my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Oracle GC tuning docs about the parallel gc:

> On a machine with N hardware threads where N is greater than 8, the
>   parallel collector uses a fixed fraction of N as the number of garbage
>   collector threads. The fraction is approximately 5/8 for large values
>   of N. At values of N below 8, the number used is N.
>   [found here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/parallel.html)

So you probable won't benefit unless your cpu is multithreaded. Also a good read is the section 5 of the aforementioned docs.